# Remove Column Headers in JasperReports jr:table component

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using JasperReports (Jaspersoft Studio for designing templates) for a project that needs both PDF and Excel output and the majority of the data is the Detail section, within a table. I know you can remove the pageHeader and columnHeader at the document level, but is it possible to remove, or only print once, the column headers within a table?

The output result:
[image: Output Format]

The report's design:
[image: JRXML Design]

Comment: Can you post the image?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have added the screen shot above. Please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column headers in the table component are meant to be repeated when the table overflows and cannot be hidden. To achieve what you want you could either:

- move the contents of your `columnHeader` into the `tableHeader` so that only the table header prints once
- or filter out the elements when performing a specific export by adding sets of properties like these:

  `<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="columnHeader"/>
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.1" value="*"/>`

  More info on filtering elements at export time [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.%7Bformat%7D.exclude.origin.%7Bsuffix%7D.%7Barbitrary_name%7D) and [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-can-i-suppress-page-headers-and-footers-when-exporting-xls).

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you so much :)